# Angular.js Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This was solved via using a service rather than a factory as described on the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uh23lrXz2mI4ukvJvxws?p=preview provided by @Incognos. Accepted answer was @Tomislav as he first mentioned using a service.

I've created a controller to handle the stores items, they're stored like such (removed reiterations to save space on here):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.product = {
      items: [
        {
          qty: 0,
          stock: 5,
          price: 99.00,
          name: 'Almond Toe Court Shoes, Patent Black',
          category: 'Womens Footerwear'
        }
      ]
    };
  });
```

I need to create a service to hold this data so it can be accessed from another view/controller. (It'll be the final cart page). I've attempted to use .factory, then in the controller $scope.products = serviceName.items; but to no avail. I've injected the service via the controller also. I'm given a $injector:modulerr error.

To clarify, the service I created is this

```
var app = angular.module("angularStoreApp", []);

app.factory("StoreService", function() {
  var products = {
    items: [
      {
        qty: 0
      }
    ]
  };
  return products;
});
```

The controller then is as such:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
      .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope, StoreService){
    $scope.product = StoreService.items;
  });
```

I'm stuck on how to put my data from the original controller into the service and then inject the service into the controller to display the items once again. To note, NOT using a service, the data is displayed in the view perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use factory, create a service which is always singleton and will hold your data:

```
var app = angular.module('angularStoreApp',[]);

app.service('StoreService',function(){

  var products={
    items:[]
  };

  this.save=function(item){
    products.items.push(item);
  };

  this.get=function(){

    return products;

  };
});
```

Inject it in your controller:

```
app.controller('storeCtrl',function($scope,StoreService){

  var item={qty:0}

  StoreService.save(item);

  $scope.product=StoreService.get();

  console.log($scope.product);

});
```

Because service is singleton it is kind of global in whole application. You can inject it in any controller and it will remember your saved values.

Comment: To expand on this. Services are `new`'d, and the same instance is then kept. Factories just return the function as it is each time, so you can call `new` on it yourself if you want.

Comment: @Tomislav, thanks for this. Though, to be clear, I need the data e.g qty to be stored so I can use this in another view later, for example, the cart. I can see the data is being stored in the controller? Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm new to angular.

Comment: It is stored during whole wab page life cycle, not in the controller but in the service. You can inject that service later in any other controller

Comment: Hey, I've used the above code, but it's not working and saying app is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: add this first: var app = angular.module('angularStoreApp',[]);   I edited my answer above.

Comment: Picking your answer as you first mentioned using a Service despite @Incognos 's helping further. Both very much appreciated. It works now and I understand what's happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

App from top to bottom using a Service:

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('buyerCtrl', function($scope, StoreService) {
  $scope.items = StoreService.items();
  $scope.buyMe = function(item) {
    StoreService.add(item);
  };
})

.service("StoreService", function() {
  var products = [];
  var items = [{
    qty: 0,
    stock: 5,
    price: 99.00,
    name: 'Almond Toe Court Shoes, Patent Black',
    category: 'Womens Footerwear'
  }, {
    qty: 0,
    stock: 5,
    price: 99.00,
    name: 'Black Lace Shoes, Patent Black',
    category: 'Mens Footerwear'
  }];
  this.items = function() {
    return items;
  };
  this.add = function(product) {
    products.push(product);
  };
  this.count = function() {
    return products.length;
  };
  this.cart = function() {
    return products;
  };
})

.controller('cartCtrl', function($scope, StoreService) {
  $scope.cart = StoreService.cart();
  $scope.cartCount = StoreService.count();
});
```

see [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uh23lrXz2mI4ukvJvxws?p=preview) (plunker updated to show multi-file)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, I've added that code to my controller, but it's not allowing anything within the store view to be loaded, that, or any other view. 

Also, var products is still being thrown as a redundant variable.

Comment: I edited and converted the factory to a service, as mentioned by @tomislav - you will need to post the additional code so that I can help any further.

Comment: would have been handy to have the HTML in the future as well... but I included a plunkr with a working "cart"

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll use your logic and try to work mine to it. Also, I have a file structure that splits the logic. I have ctrl.js, view.html, service.js, store.js (for the view) would your logic work having the service.js in another file?

Comment: as long as you define it in the same module name 'angularStoreApp', otherwise, you will have to inject that module into the app

Comment: Same module name will be used, there's no need at the moment to create a new module. Sorry, I'm still learning the logic! I'll get back if this works/doesn't and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @BillyPurvis I updated the plunker to demonstrate how to break it into multiple files... HTH

Comment: If it works, please select @tomislav as the correct answer since he brought up the right answer to your question first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82760/discussion-between-billy-purvis-and-incognos).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
angular.module('angularStoreApp')
      .controller('storeCtrl', function($scope, StoreService){
        $scope.product = StoreService;
      });
```

but make sure, your app is initialised only once.

```
var app = angular.module("angularStoreApp", []);
```

this line, afterwards, should be,

```
angular.module("angularStoreApp");
```

Comment: Hey, Z.a, I've done the first. 

I assume you want me to add 

var app = angular.module("angularStoreApp", []);

into the controller? It's already being initialised only once in the services file. 

To note, they are in seperate files within the same child directory. So services.js and StoreCtrl.js are within the same directory of "store"..

Comment: doesnt matter where it's really.  u should use this line once, and preferably before anything else,
angular.module("angularStoreApp", []);
never use it with brackets again.
u can do this to create controllers, services, etc
angular.module("angularStoreApp").controller, factory, etc

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a direct reference to the service's exposed `item` collection inside each one of the consuming controllers, and manipulate the reference directly.

The following example uses this pattern and two controllers to demonstrate the behavior:

```js
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);
 
module.service('StoreService', function(){
 this.items = 
   [
        {
          qty: 0,
          stock: 5,
          price: 99.00,
          name: 'Almond Toe Court Shoes, Patent Black',
          category: 'Womens Footerwear'
        }
      ] 
   ;
});
         
      
module.controller('element1Controller', function($scope, StoreService){
  $scope.items = StoreService.items;
  
  $scope.add = function(){
    
    $scope.items.push({
          qty: 2,
          stock: 10,
          price: 9.00,
          name: 'Random Item',
          category: 'Womens Footerwear'
        });
              

}
});

module.controller('element2Controller', function($scope, StoreService){
  $scope.items = StoreService.items;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='myapp'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="element1Controller">
  Controller 1<br />
  {{items}}
  <br />
  <button ng-click='add()'>Add Item to Cart</button>
  
</div>

  <br />

  <div ng-controller="element1Controller">
  Controller 2<br />
  {{items}}
</div>
</html>
```